# how to create new file without restarting?

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, video-encoding, video-capture

I am using string

```
ffmpeg64 -f decklink -i "DeckLink Studio 2@9" -f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe -c:v mpeg2video -pix_fmt yuv422p -b:v 10M -vf fps=30 -s 1280x720 -g 30 -g 12 -mbd rd -trellis 1 -flags +mv0 -cmp 0 -subcmp 2 -c:a aac -b:a 128K -ar 48000 -y "output.mp4"
```

to capture video.

I need to create a new video file on command, without stopping the recording process. How to do it?

Comment: Why do you need to create a new file? Do the new files have to be created at arbitrary times, or at specified durations?

Comment: arbitrary times. By By external signals GPIO.